# Expanding Snippets in evil-insert-mode

Tags: spacemacs, yasnippet

I just moved to spacemacs from vim and am a complete newbie with emacs.

I cannot figure out how to expand yasnippets while in evil-insert-mode. I know yasnippet is available because I can choose from the available snippets using `Spc i s`. However I'd like to be able to `<Tab>` expand them.  What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried [company-mode](https://github.com/company-mode/company-mode)? I think it is very handy when dealing with auto completion---it has many different backends, and yasnippet is one of them.

Comment: yeah, spacemacs comes bundled with auto-complete and company-mode. I'm not sure which one is in effect and not really sure how to find out.

Comment: Use `describe-mode` (it's on `<f1> m` in default Emacs), and search in 1st paragraph (where it says "Enabled minor modes: ...").

Comment: thanks! it says company is enabled and yas. strangely I dont see company-mode's dropdown box with suggestions when I type and the yassnippets dont expand

Answer (score 13):

`M-/` is the default binding to expand snippets not `TAB`.  You can find this out with `Spc ?` then searching for `yas`

Comment: I have a stupid question - what does ```M-/``` mean? :)

Comment: @aikeru not stupid. it means {option} + /

Comment: so ```M``` is the ALT key on, say, a Linux or Windows machine, right?

Comment: I think so yes.

Comment: Should I remap `yas-expand` to `TAB` or not? There must be a good reason not to since that's the default, but I'm not understanding it. If I should remap, is there an option for this in Spacemacs?

Answer (score 3):

`M-x yas-expand`, you can `C-h f yas-expand` to check which hotkey is assigned.

`company` is an auto-completion framework which supports many backends. `company-yasnippet` could be its backend. If you use company-yasnippet, please check https://github.com/company-mode/company-mode/issues/492

I use yasnippets independently and assign global hotkey `M-j` to `yas-expand`

Answer (score 0):

As I can see Spacemacs is not using the classic yas-expand but uses hippie expand which triggers yas-expand:

```
M-/ runs the command hippie-expand (found in global-map), which is an
interactive autoloaded compiled Lisp function in ‘hippie-exp.el’.

 is bound to M-/.

(hippie-expand ARG)

:around advice: ‘ad-Advice-hippie-expand’

Try to expand text before point, using multiple methods.
The expansion functions in ‘hippie-expand-try-functions-list’ are
tried in order, until a possible expansion is found.  Repeated
application of ‘hippie-expand’ inserts successively possible
expansions.
With a positive numeric argument, jumps directly to the ARG next
function in this list.  With a negative argument or just SPC u,
undoes the expansion.
```